# Ошибка при удалении из файла

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

при удалении ошибка ,что я не так сделал ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Schoolboy
{
    string f;
    string i;
    string o;
    int Class{};
    string PhoneNumber;
    int GradeMaths{};
    int GradePhysics{};
    int GradeRussianLanguage{};
    int GradeLiterature{};
};

ofstream file;

int ValidationGrade(int g)
{
    cin >> g;
    while (g < 0 || g > 5)
    {
        if (g <= 0)cout << "Error, the score cannot be less than 0. Please re-enter: ";
        else cout << "Error, rating cannot be more than 5. Please re-enter:";
        cin >> g;
    }
    return g;
}

void VvodFile(Schoolboy* Array, int size)
{   
    int g = 0;

    fstream file("Schoolboy.txt", ios::out);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter F: ";
        cin >> Array[i].f;
        cout << "Enter I: ";
        cin >> Array[i].i;
        cout << "Enter O: ";
        cin >> Array[i].o;
        cout << "Enter Class: ";
        cin >> Array[i].Class;
        cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
        cin >> Array[i].PhoneNumber;
        cout << "Enter Grade Maths: ";
        Array[i].GradeMaths = ValidationGrade(g);
        cout << "Enter Grade Physics: ";
        Array[i].GradePhysics = ValidationGrade(g);
        cout << "Enter Grade Russian Language: ";
        Array[i].GradeRussianLanguage = ValidationGrade(g);
        cout << "Enter Grade Literature: ";
        Array[i].GradeLiterature = ValidationGrade(g);

        file << Array[i].f;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].i;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].o;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].Class;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].PhoneNumber;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].GradeMaths;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].GradePhysics;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].GradeRussianLanguage;
        file << "\n";
        file << Array[i].GradeLiterature;
        file << "\n";
    }

    file.close();
}

void VivodFile()
{
    Schoolboy p;
    system("cls");
    fstream file("Schoolboy.txt", ios::in);
    do
    {
        file >> p.f;
        file >> p.i;
        file >> p.o;
        file >> p.Class;
        file >> p.PhoneNumber;
        file >> p.GradeMaths;
        file >> p.GradePhysics;
        file >> p.GradeRussianLanguage;
        file >> p.GradeLiterature;
        if (file.eof())break;
        cout << " " << p.f << " " << p.i << " " << p.o << " " << p.Class << " " << p.PhoneNumber << " " << p.GradeMaths << " " << p.GradePhysics << " " << p.GradeRussianLanguage << " " << p.GradeLiterature << "\n";

    } while (!file.eof());
    file.close();
}

void DeleteFile()
{
    Schoolboy p;

    system("cls");
    fstream file("Schoolboy.txt", ios::in);
    fstream filecopy("Schoolboycopy.txt", ios::app | ios::out);

    do
    {
        file >> p.f;
        file >> p.i;
        file >> p.o;
        file >> p.Class;
        file >> p.PhoneNumber;
        file >> p.GradeMaths;
        file >> p.GradePhysics;
        file >> p.GradeRussianLanguage;
        file >> p.GradeLiterature;
        if (file.eof())break;
        if (p.GradeMaths > 2 && p.GradePhysics > 2 && p.GradeRussianLanguage > 2 && p.GradeLiterature > 2)
        {
            filecopy << p.f;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.i;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.o;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.Class;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.PhoneNumber;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.GradeMaths;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.GradePhysics;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.GradeRussianLanguage;
            filecopy << "\n";
            filecopy << p.GradeLiterature;
            filecopy << "\n";
        }
    } while (!file.eof());

    file.close();
    filecopy.close();

    rename("Schoolboy.txt", "Schoolboyold.txt");
    remove("Schoolboy.txt");
    rename("Schoolboycopy.txt", "Schoolboy.txt");
    remove("Schoolboy.txt");
    VivodFile();
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Enter size:";
    cin >> size;

    Schoolboy* Array = new Schoolboy[size];
    
    VvodFile(Array, size);
    VivodFile();
    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "Remove all items that have 2 of at least one item:";
    DeleteFile();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Опишите конкретней ошибку? Что-то выводит или что-то не происходит?

Comment: Просто бесконечный цикл , и не понятые данные

Comment: Мне нужно удалить данные из файла если у кого есть оценка по какому то предмету

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в этих строчках:

```
rename("Schoolboy.txt", "Schoolboyold.txt");
remove("Schoolboy.txt");
rename("Schoolboycopy.txt", "Schoolboy.txt");
remove("Schoolboy.txt");
```

Сначала вы переименовываете файл `Schoolboy`, а потом пытаете удалить файл с таким же названием, а далее переименовываете `Schoolboycopy` и потом по факту удаляете этот файл.

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно чтобы `Schoolboycopy` переименовался в `Schoolboy`, а после копия удалилась.

Тогда вот пример:

```
remove("Schoolboy.txt");
rename("Schoolboycopy.txt", "Schoolboy.txt");
```

Сначала мы убираем старую версию, и новую скопированную версию мы переименовываем на `Schoolboy`